# Why isn't winterba.sh being used for Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, domain-names

Recently, I found out [from a blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012) that Winter Bash 2012 used quite an interesting domain, [http://winterba.sh](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116124205/http://winterba.sh).

Just curious, why isn't it being reused, since it's a fitting domain name and that it's redirected to stackpromos.com?